# Fatal error compiling: java.lang.Il legalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor

Tags: java, reactjs, maven, pom.xml

I already installed Lombok and got the latest Java, set all System Variables as M2 or MAVEN and JAVA_HOME. Still have an error. POM is building all right and all files such as mvnw and mvnw.cmd work well. But when i try to run it all, by *mvn clean install*, there is a failure:

```
mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------------< com.aegon:aegon >---------------------------
[INFO] Building aegon 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ aegon ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\48512\Desktop\BEST\BEST\17 KV\projekty\dostałem-rozpakowane\system-biletowy-backend-master\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ aegon ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 57 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ aegon ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 50 source files to C:\Users\48512\Desktop\BEST\BEST\17 KV\projekty\dostałem-rozpakowane\system-biletowy-backend-master\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.672 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-26T10:54:35+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project aegon: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.Il
legalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module @0x6f4adaab) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironm
ent (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0x6f4adaab -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Here is my pom.xml (aegon) file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.aegon</groupId>
    <artifactId>aegon</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>aegon</name>
    <description>karnavauli 2.0</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

If You need something more, write.
I have been searching for a solution all yesterday and nothing changed.
Also this is not ma own project, i took over and i am still waiting for a meeting with autor, but he said it should work without any problems. It does not. I know a bit of Java, but not wiht react and springboot.
Please help.

Comment: What is the output of `mvn --version`?

Comment: My first guess is, you use an JRE not a JDK

Comment: First use most recent version of Spring boot because 2.1.7.RELEASE is out of date... also use most recent version of maven-compiler-plugin....

Comment: Thats the output of mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.6
Java version: 18.0.2.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1
Default locale: pl_PL, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Answer (score 2):

Your spring boot version is quite old. Upgrade it to latest one. If you can't, then provide the latest version of lombok in your pom.xml explicitely instead of default using from springboot.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
   <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
   <version>1.18.24</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: OH man it worked, your great, let's see if there will be any other problems. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good to hear that. Hope everything will work now. Please vote the answer to help others if someone also facing the same kind of problems.